# Selenium element is hidden behind floating header

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The Selenium webdriver locator always puts elements on top of the page if scrolling is needed, but it wont take into account a floating header. At the moment I created a workaround with

```
Actions actions = new Actions(this.webdriver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP).perform();
```

Isnt there a nicer solution to tell the webdriver to center an element in the middle of the screen instead or with a fixed distance to the top?

The orange part is from the button the blue part is the header:

[hidden button in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eQxD.png)

Comment: additional information about the question, like a screenshot of the html page, actual html etc will give more context to your question

Comment: adjust your scrolling in such a way that required element in visible stage..you can take help from robot class, javascript executor also to scroll as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the element into view using javascript. Here is a possible solution:

1. Bring the element into the view port using selenium api.
2. Use javascript to figure out if the element is obstructed by another element, (floating header / footer etc...).
3. Use javascript to scroll to the middle of the view port.

See the javascript utility class I created here: https://github.com/gterre/stuff

usage...JavascriptUtils.bringIntoView(WebElement element);

I'm sure you can modify the script to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I choose to hide that floating element.

```
top = dr.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@node-type="top_all"]')
dr.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:none')", top)
```

After that, move to the element I want, I can even add an offset.

Comment: Works for a footer, pending a slight adaptation: '//footer' is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Selenium also has the ability to not scroll items to the top of the window before interacting with them (and therefore hiding them behind a floating header) but instead to the bottom.

This is achieved via the 'elementScrollBehavior' capability which can be set to 1 to scroll stuff to the bottom.

See [this stack overflow for how it's done in capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439701/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-set-capabilities-elementscrollbehavior-to-1-for-a#37171021).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this, so you just need to define in which cases your element is not in scope and add this method, it will automatically scroll it into view:

`public void scroll_element_into_view(WebElementFacade element) {
    int Y = (element.getLocation().getY() - 200);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
    js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollTo(0," + Y + ");");}`

Works for every element you can find by id, css, xpath or whatsoever.

Comment: This will only work if the scrollable container is the window.

Comment: what is the method "getDriver() "?