# Capybara + Selenium - Element is not clickable at point (388.3833312988281, 8.333328247070312). Other element would receive the click

Tags: ruby, capybara

Im having a problem with a button.
Every time i tried to click, i receive this message

" Element is not clickable at point (388.3833312988281, 8.333328247070312). Other element would receive the click. "

Im using Firefox, and Capybara + ruby, and selenium ( not webdriver )

Heres the code of the button

I want to click on the Add button

What can i do ?

```
<div class="box08-2 collapseBoxContent" style="margin-top: 0px">
  <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH" style="margin-top: 0px">
     <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH_wtContent" style="margin-top: 0px">
       <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH_wtContent_wtCtnBody" data-webbtests="CompraWeb.Request_Edit.ItemsWB.divCtnBody">
         <div class="btn04 btn04v5 box20v10">
           <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH_wtContent_RichWidgets_wt42_block_wtDropDownButtonRoot" class="Menu_DropDownButton OSInline">
             <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH_wtContent_RichWidgets_wt42_block_wtDropDownButtonElement" class="Menu_TopMenu">
              <div id="wt32_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt11_block_wtMainContent_wtMainContent_wtItemsWB_Huge_WebbBaseTheme_wt31_block_wt8_wtCollapsibleContentPH_wtContent_RichWidgets_wt42_block_wtMenuItem">
                  <span data-webbtests="CompraWeb.Request_Edit.ResumeRequestItemsWB.lblActions">Add</span>
```

Comment: I think this is an issue with the firefox version you are using and selenium version.Can you post the gem versions of selenium you are using and also the firefox version.                                                                                    Try using firefox 46.0.1 it works for me  with Selenium 2.53

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually appear when the DOM either is not ready or is changing.

So you should wait until the page become stable, all async scripts are finished, images loaded and so on. Ads also could be an issue, as they could change the page.

Please have a look here for waiting (by the way, I'd recommend to use watir webdriver on top of Selenium):
http://watir.github.io/docs/waiting/

Here are steps for reducing probability of this issue:

- wrap this code in rescue block and retry when it happens
- disable images loading
- install AdBlock or similar extension
- use `wait_` helpers in Watir
- try to avoid using complicated css selectors. Use something like `button(text: 'Add')` instead
- if you use it, try to select an element as close to click action in your code as it possible

Comment: but if i wanna use without watir...how can i do ?

Comment: This answer is wrong on a number of counts. 1 - the question asks about using Capybara, "switch to watir" is not an answer to that.  2- rescue and retry is a bad solution to pretty much any issue in testing since it means your tests are non determinant.  3. install AdBlock - What would that have to do with with an element being covered on the page?  4. button(text: 'Add')  - there are no elements in the OPs html that would match that.

Comment: @RodrigoSantos just do not use watir, implement other points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your "not webdriver" comment, since the only way to use selenium with Capybara is via the selenium-webdriver gem.

Judging by the y position of the error you're getting (8.333328247070312) it's likely that the button you're trying to click is behind a fixed header.  This is either because you haven't clicked an element necessary to make the button slide out from behind the header or because the page was longer than the screen and selenium-webdriver scrolled the page until the element was at the top (which ends up behind your header).  If you don't have a fixed footer on the page then you can change selenium-webdriver, via the `elementScrollBehavior` property, to scroll elements to the bottom instead of the top - see [Selenium WebDriver : How do I set capabilities elementScrollBehavior to 1 for a FireFox configuration in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439701/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-set-capabilities-elementscrollbehavior-to-1-for-a)
. If that doesn't work for you then you can use `execute_script` and JS to scroll the page so the element moves out from under the header